# How to make an included menu / submenu / separate screen in pxelinux?

Tags: pxe, syslinux

I have the following menu on my LAN:

```
UI menu.c32
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 300
ONTIMEOUT local

MENU TITLE In The Moon PXE Menu (Sagittarius-A)

LABEL WinPE64
MENU LABEL Windows PE x64
KERNEL /memdisk
INITRD /images/WinPE_amd64.iso
APPEND iso

LABEL Ubuntu64
MENU LABEL Ubuntu x64
KERNEL /images/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
APPEND ro root=/dev/sda1 initrd=/images/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic

LABEL Memtest86
MENU LABEL Memtest86+
kernel images/memtest86
```

Which gives me the following menu:

[image]

Now I would like to add Ubuntu installer to it. Better is separate screen or submenu.

I got the following files:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

They have the following config there:

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/menu.cfg
default ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 0
```

from which I think, that the only data I need, is inside `ubuntu-installer` folder.

Now how to add menu from `ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/menu.cfg` in it's totality into my menu, leaving it mostly work?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want is to chainload from your menu the pxelinux.0 included somewhere under 'ubuntu-installer/'. You might run into some directory issues but they can bi fixed.